# set action class parameters in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I'm trying to set parameter value `bulkID` from form in ftl file to action class, but unable to set. Following is the code:

struts.xml file

```xml
<action name="bulk" class="com.action.BulkChangeMainAction">
    <result name="input" type="freemarker">/resources/templates/bulk-changes.ftl</result>
</action>
```

BulkChangeMainAction.java

```java
public class BulkChangeMainAction  {

    private int bulkID;

    public int getBulkID() {
        return bulkID;
    }

    public void setBulkID(int bulkID) {
        this.bulkID = bulkID;
    }

     public String input() {
        return INPUT;
    }   
}
```

bulk-changes.ftl

```xml
<form id='filter-form' action="<@s.url action='bulk' method='input'/>" method="post" name="filterForm">
    <input type="text" id="bulkID" name="bulkID"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Any good reason for using `method` in `<s:url>`? You need to enable DMI.

Comment: DMI is enabled. it is a third party code to which I'm making enhancement. There is another HTML element in the same form : <select id='stageID' name="stageID"> , whose value is set in the same action class, Im not sure how that is done. I was trying to do something similar to set value of bulkID. I thought parameters interceptor does that job. Is there anything Im missing?

Comment: So your method is being called? Try to use another method and result name.

Comment: yes the method is being called but the variable valuefor bulkID is not setting

Comment: What are you posting to it? `input` is special result don't use it for success workflow.

Comment: Aleksandr, one base question - when should the the parameter bulkID be set in the flow? - the user sees the form and enters some number in the bulkID input box and clicks on submit button. So from where and when the setter function setBulkID(int bulkID) for bulkID be called? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the struts2 form tag and sth like the following (I assume input is the action you want to call?):

```
<s:form action="bulk.input.action" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="bulkId" label="Bulk Id" />
    <s:submit value="Confirm" />
</s:form>
```

Here is a nice complete example too:
http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/struts/handling-form-data-in-struts2

if you need to keep the current format you have, please try changing int to String or Integer and see if it works.

Comment: Im trying to do without using <s:form> as there already exists dropdown in the same form which is working. Please suggest some changes to the above code

Comment: Have you tried changing the type of bulkId to see if it works? try changing it to String and test to see if that works.